# IN Entity framework How to select all the Data which is = to an id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE id == tmpId
```

What is entity framework query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DbContext.db.Where(item => item.id == tmpId);
```

In your example **db** appears to be a table name, but I doubt that is what you meant since DB usually refers to database. But the syntax is:

```
DbContext.[tablename].Where([query]);
```